# Match URL using Regex

Tags: php, regex, symfony, symfony4

I use following regex pattern in PHP (Symfony framework) to match URL

```
^/api/v1/account/verify
^/api/v1/account/register
^/api/v1/account/forgot-password
```

I now have a following URL

```
/api/v1/payment/{token}/success/jJBePenWo0eN
```

`{token}` will consist of dynamic values, but string "jJBePenWo0eN" will always be static how do I make a match that will satisfy the above URL?

**Update: 1**

I am looking for something like this

```
^/api/v1/payment/[a-zA-Z0-9]/success/jJBePenWo0eN
```

However this is not working

Comment: `^/api/v1/payment/[^/]+/success/jJBePenWo0eN`

Comment: I think you only have to add a quantifier `+` after the character class `^/api/v1/payment/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/success/jJBePenWo0eN` https://regex101.com/r/aegPtU/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a regex like below:

```
'/^\/api\/v1\/payment\/(.+?)\/success\/jJBePenWo0eN$/'
```

where we match the string from start to end(notice the `^` and `$` symbols) and match the {token} value greedily in `(.+?)` group.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

if(preg_match('/^\/api\/v1\/payment\/(.+?)\/success\/jJBePenWo0eN$/','/api/v1/payment/{token}/success/jJBePenWo0eN',$matches) === 1){
    print_r($matches);    
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/2pjjq

Comment: This `(.+?)` works, thank you, even `[^/]+` works, what does `(.+?)` exactly try to match?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar It matches the `{token}`.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar `[^/]+` is a negated character class which will match 1 or more times any char except `/` The `.*?` is a non greedy quantifier which will match 0 or more times any character except a newline.Using `[^/]+` will be a bit more efficient as `.*?` will have backtracking.

Comment: @Thefourthbird That's true but efficiency factor is negligible for such small strings.